# Read JSON with infinity in R

Tags: r, json, infinity

I'm looking for a way to read a matrix containing an infinite value that is encoded in a JSON file into R. I'm currently getting the furthest using the RJSONIO library for this (rjson and rjsonlite produce an error in my case).

A minimal illustrative example is as follows:
(*EDIT: this example is not general enough, the method I'm looking for can handle non-finite values that are not generated in R as well*)

```
> library("RJSONIO")

> M <- matrix(c(1:5, Inf), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE); M

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5  Inf

> fromJSON(toJSON(M))

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 5

[[3]][[2]]
NULL
```

Executing this code will also produce a warning that the non-finite values may not be appropriately represented in JSON.

I'm wondering if there is a work-around to get the infinite values to be correctly represented during the file reading? I'm fine with the file being stored as a list after reading, but not with the last element not being a numeric vector.

Note that I'm not really looking for a post-processing method that converts the non-numeric vectors after having read the entire file: I already have this, but the actual files I'm working with are quite large and nested, so I prefer to not have to rerun through them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several (newer) JSON libraries to choose from -- I use `jsonlite` a bit and it has no problem here:

```
R> library(jsonlite)
R> M <- matrix(c(1:5, Inf), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE); M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5  Inf
R> fromJSON(toJSON(M))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5  Inf
R>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not general enough for my case. Perhaps my example was not sufficient enough. The actual json file I'm working with was constructed in Python, and the resulting "Infinity" is not recognized using jsonlite::fromJSON (though as.numeric("Infinity") does correctly result in Inf in R). It helps to know that jsonlite::fromJSON does recognize "Inf" though, another possibility now is to look if it's possible to encode my file in this way when writing it out from Python.

Comment: In general it helps to write in your question what your question actually is.  So what you really want, apparently, is a JSON-based serialization from Python?

Comment: I'm more concretely looking for an efficient method to write out a json file including matrices (represented as lists of lists) containing non finite values (numpy.inf) in Python, and reading them back again into R. The separate handling of infinite values can be either done in Python or R, but needs to be at writing/reading time.